# a less expensive way of grouping entries by category

Tags: channel-entries, categories, stash, performance, caching

I'm trying to figure out if there's a more performant way of getting entries grouped by category.

As you can see, I'm using NSM Categories module. Right now, this costing me 263 queries and 5 seconds of load. If I remove my if statements (only there because we have different markup for the first entry of a category and also spit out an opening ul element), performance increases dramatically using 63 queries in 2 seconds.

Can anyone suggest any improvements? With something so intensive, we'll be using CE Cache anyway but would like to improve even more before we get to that stage.

```
{exp:nsm_categories:archive
            enable="entries"
            category_channel_entry_limit="6"
            category="3|6|5|1|7|2"
        }
            <div class="category category--{category_url_title}">
                <h3 class="category__title"><a class="category__link" href="/channel/{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a></h3>

                {category_channel_entries}
                {if {category_channel_entry_count} == '1'}
                <div class="category__firstentry relative" style=
                "background-image: url(''); background-size: cover;">
                <div class="category__overlay absolute"></div><a class="title relative" href="">{title}</a>
                    <p class="author relative">by {exp:playa:children var_prefix="children" entry_id="{entry_id}" backspace="5"}{children:title}</a> and {/exp:playa:children}</p>
                </div>
                {/if}

                {if {category_channel_entry_count} == '2'}
                <ul class="category__entries">
                {/if}
                {if {category_channel_entry_count} > '1'}
                <li class="entry__single">
                    <a href="/article/{url_title}">{title}</a>
                </li>
                {/if}

                {/category_channel_entries}
            </div>
            {/exp:nsm_categories:archive}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my experimentation here brought me to Stash.

Much more succinct now and gives me everything I need in just 66 queries before caching :)

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" channel="articles"}
     {categories}
      {exp:stash:append_list name="news_{category_id}"}
       {stash:item_title}{title} - {entry_date {gv_date_short}}{/stash:item_title}
      {/exp:stash:append_list}
     {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}


{exp:channel:category_archive channel="articles" show="not 4|22|24" style="linear"}
  {categories}
    <h2>{category_name} - {category_id}</h2>
    {exp:stash:get_list limit="6" name="news_{category_id}"}
    {if count == '1'}
    <h3>{item_title}</h3>
    {/if}
    {if count == '2'}
      <ul class="list">
    {/if}
    {if count > '1'}
    <li>{item_title}</li>
    {/if}
    {if count == total_results}
      </ul>
    {/if}
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
    {/categories}
{/exp:channel:category_archive}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting approach. I would typically have used Stash to

- set a list of all my entries (capturing categories for each of them)
- set a list of all the categories I want

And then used nested `{exp:stash:get_list}` with `match_against` to get entries ordered by categories. Same principle as [this gist by Mark Croxton](https://gist.github.com/croxton/6219973)

Don't know if that would lower your number of queries, though.

Answer (score 0):

When using if conditionals you're going to have the overhead of parsing the template code within every condition and then getting rid of the ones that don't apply, for *every* iteration of your loop.

Using Switchee should greatly reduce this overhead as it's going to get rid of the non-matching conditions and only parse the one that matches.

I've seen some good performance improvements just by moving to using Switchee rather than using regular conditionals.

Comment: yeah, I found that as well. I've actually even had to ditch this approach because when I introduced a Playa field, the query count went through the roof. Now using the query module with an embedded template, I'm sure there must be a way to do this with Stash that's less intensive but I can't continue to spend time on it.

Comment: custom queries that don't retrieve every field and parse every entry through every condition :)

Comment: yeah, I like the query module

Comment: It is restricted though. For anything beyond the basics you could wrap your custom queries in a plugin.