# Display latest entries in categories, only display distinct items per category

Tags: categories

I have a homepage with 4 blocks. Each block contains the latest entry from a category. Right now if one item is assigned to multiple categories then it displays in all the blocks.

How can I pull the latest item from each category and ensure that only distinct items appear in category block?

Thanks,

Comment: You may get some mileage from this approach http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/a-less-expensive-way-of-grouping-entries-by-category

Comment: Thanks Steven. I'm not familiar with that but I'll take a look.

Comment: Steven, if I shared my current code snippet would you be able to assist me with implementing the solution you shared? I'm not an EE developer so I'm not familiar with some of the functionality. Thanks